# Notation for the projection of a relation onto one component space

Tags: notation, relations

Suppose $R \subseteq S \times T$, i.e. $R$ is a relation between $S$ and $T$.

What is the notation for the projection of $R$ onto $T$, i.e. for $\{t: \forall t \in T, \exists s \in S, s.t. (s,t) \in R \}$?

Is it $R_T$?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no standard notation. I normally define the projection maps $\pi_0:S\times T\to S$ and $\pi_1:S\times T\to T$ and write $\pi_1[R]$, giving it a name if it’s going to come up very often.

Comment: You could call this the "domain" of the relation, as an extension of the idea of the domain of a function.